# Consulta a Servidores DNS

Tags: servidor, dns, windows-server-2012

Tengo una duda que me ronda acerca de las consultas DNS a la hora de realizar una petición a un determinado Dominio.
Si registro un dominio, por ejemplo, **www.midominio.com**, a este se le asigna una determinada ip, por ejemplo **55.44.33.22.11**, a su vez mi domino dispone de 2 servidores dns, por ejemplo, **ns1.domaindsn.org** y **ns2.domaindns.org**. Por otro lado tengo en mi domicilio un servicio de internet y realizo una petición a www.midominio.com, pero las dns que tengo configuradas en mi PC son las de mi proovedor ISP o en su defecto las de Google **8.8.8.8/8.8.4.4**. 
A la petición de www.midominio.com,  quien esta respondiendo ??. Es, quizás, el servidor DNS que tengo configurado en mi PC (8.8.8.8) quien solicita la traducción a ns1.domaindsn.org o en su defecto a  ns2.domaindns.org ?

Un saludo y gracias

Answer (score 0):

EL servidor DNS que tenga tu pc es el que va a hacer la peticion y si no la tiene la busca en otro dns o en uno de los dns principales

Comment: Entonces los DNS de el dominio que he creado que función cumplen ?,  son los que funcionan como servidores autoritarios ?, quiero decir, si el servidor de google responde con la ip de midominio.com es porque este a su vez consulto en algún momento a ns1.domaindsn.org ?

Comment: Los dns de tu dominio mandan la peticion de propagacion a los dns principales que son los que distribuyen la direcion a los demas dns, para mayor informacion: https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Servidor_ra%C3%ADz

Comment: Me quedo claro. Muchas gracias :) !!!